# File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body and more

Tags: beamer, graphics

It's my first time in Beamer, and i want to make a titlepage as well as those seen on the net (and those done by my university teachers XD)
First of all:

```
\documentclass[trans,9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\tiny
\title{Trabajo: El nombre del trabajo}
\author{Pablo \'Alvarez Rodr\'iguez}
\institute{Universidad de Oviedo}
\subject{F\'isica Moderna o T\'ecnicas experimentales}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\includegraphics[\textscale]{UNIOVIlogo.jpg}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\'Indice}
    \tableofcontents
                %añadir distintas partes
                %mínimo 1 diapo
                    %; 2 máximo
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \section{Introducci\'on}
    \frametitle{Introducci\'on}
    En este trabajo os voy a hablar sobre...
\end{frame}

    %----Para Moderna:
    \section{Breve repaso a part\'iculas elementales (1 diapo con imagen)}
    \begin{frame}
        content...
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Leptones (1 diapo)}
    \begin{frame}
        content...
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{Bosones (1 diapo)}
    \begin{frame}
        content...
    \end{frame}
    \section{Formaci\'on de los neutrinos (1 o 2 diapos)}
    \begin{frame}
        content...
    \end{frame}
    \section{Formaci\'on de los fotones (1 o 2 diapos)}
    \begin{frame}
        content...
    \end{frame}
    %En las siguientes se mencionarán los distintos experimentos 
    \section{Utilidad f\'isica: Estudio de los fotones (1 diapo)}
    \begin{frame}
    \section{Utilidad f\'isica: Estudio de los neutrinos (1 diapo)}
    \subsection{Experimento \'Opera (1 diapo)}
    %siguiente es conclusión
    %----Para Experimentales: 
    %\section{Introducción
    %\section{Montaje
    %\section{Procedimiento
    %\section{Discusión de Resultados
    %siguiente es conclusión (como el informe)

    \begin{frame}
        \section{Conclusi\'on y Bibliograf\'ia}
        \frametitle{Conclusi\'on}
        Para terminar, me gustaría concluir que...

        %Moderna:
        Las mejores part\'iculas para ver el universo son...
        %Experimentales:
        %Como si acabara el informe
        \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Bibliograf\'ia}
        \begin{thebibliography}{10}
            \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[book]
            \bibitem{Author}
            \newblock{\emph{F\'isica }}%volumen y edición
            \newblock Paul A. Tipler
          %si es moderna, también Gene Mosca. Añadir año de la 6ª edición: 2012%
          %para experimentales
      \end{thebibliography}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Then, after all of this (that is only a sketch for two works i have to do), my problems:
-I have this error

```
File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body
```

I have to say that before finding this lonely-error I found lots of \end{frame} related errors. Are this two errors related?

Also, as I am tired with errors, how is the easiest way to insert an image? (.jpg or .png)

Comment: @Werner Is indenting `\end{frame}` not only a problem when using the `fragile` option?

Comment: @samcarter: Maybe; haven't checked. Your reference to the superfluous `\begin{frame}` is problematic, of course.

Comment: sooo, i dont ident here...

Comment: @Pablo: Do you see the `\begin{frame}` without a corresponding `\end{frame}`?

Comment: There is? O-o??

Comment: Now, how can i center the image.jpg??

Answer (score 11):

The problem is caused by the superfluous

```
\begin{frame}
```

in line 60

Comment: Thanks, sam. You know, I personally think all of this was identation

Answer (score -1):

Every \begin{frame} should have an \end{frame}... Please check for it

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you show the OP which frame environment is incomplete with a working example?